# Positioning several items inside a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I understand this has been asked a million times, but i am only making my own post after exhausting all the other posts without success. I don't want to use absolute positioning because of the risk of overlapping (especially when its being used in mobile version).

[Attached is an image of the 3 elements inside the div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo4ju.png)

Currently the logo and the search bar are holding the right kind of positions but i have used padding to achieve this and i'd rather have a way of having it vertically centered in all browsers.

And my main issue is the title which i just cant think of a way to horizontally and vertically align. 
Also note the header is currently inside the col-md-8 div. I would want it outside that ofcourse to have it completely in the middle of the header div. Unfortunately though when i try removing the header out of this, it tends to push the other 2 elements down.

Here is the relevant html:

```
 <div class="header w3-container" >       
        <!-- <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"> -->
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img class="displayed" src="images/genericperson.png"/>

                </div>
                <div class="headline" >
                    <h1> SRC ONLINE </h1>  */NEED THIS HEADER CENTERED VERTICALLY AND HORIZONTALLY */

                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 ">   

            <form action="search.php" method="post">
                <div class="input-group search">
                    <input name="search" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button name="submit" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form><!-- search form -->

       </div>

   </div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.header{


    /*background-color: #434A54;*/
    background-color: #00001a;
    padding-bottom:20px;



    width:100%;


}

.logo img{

    padding-top:15px;

    max-width:10%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
 }




.headline h1{



    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;

    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.5em;
    color:white;


}
```

If need may be, here is the source code to the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Website developing</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>


  <style>

 body, html {
  height: 100%;

}

     .widget_Style{

         margin-top: 20px;

     }     


h1{

    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
    .header{


        /*background-color: #434A54;*/
        background-color: #00001a;
        padding-bottom:20px;



        width:100%;


    }

    .logo img{

        padding-top:15px;

        max-width:10%;
        height:auto;
        float:left;
     }




    .headline h1{



        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;

        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:1.5em;
        color:white;


    }

     .contentBase{

         background-color:#333;
         position:relative;
         padding:0;
         margin:0;
         clear:both;

     }
     .author{
         color:white;
         float:left;
         border-radius:0;
         height:100%;

     }
     .contentBase a:hover{

      color:white;   
     }
     .btn-styling{
         color:white;
        background-color:red;
        float:right;
        border-radius:0;

     }

    .search{

        padding-top:40px;
        float:right;
        vertical-align: middle;

}

     .content_Box{


         background-color: #EEEEEE;
         padding-left: 10px;
         padding-top:5px;
         padding-bottom:5px;
     }


  /* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    position: relative;


}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-right: 1px solid #00001a;


}



.noBorder{
    border-right: none;  
}

#categoryRight{
    float:right;        
}

#lastli{
    border-right: none;

}

.navigation{

    background-color:#333;
}

#loginimage{
    padding-bottom:8px;
    height:25px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.margintop{

    margin-top:10px;
}

     .mainContent{



     }

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: red;}

/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  /*ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;} */
  ul.topnav li{display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
       img.displayed {
   display: block;
    margin: auto;
           float:none;
 }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens */
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}

#categoryRight{
        float:none;

        }



  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;

  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    border:none;



  }

}



li a, .dropbtn {

    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width:100%;

}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;


}

li.dropdown {

    z-index: 1000;


}

.dropdown-content {
   display: none;
  list-style:none; 
  padding:0; 
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 


}

.dropdown-content  li{
 display:block; padding:0; margin:0; width:100%;


}

     .dropdown-content a {
  display:block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:100%;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{

             background-color: #333;
             display:block;


     }

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #333;
      }

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block; !important



}    

  </style>







  <body> 


  <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
      </script>


   <div class="header w3-container" >       
        <!-- <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"> -->
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img class="displayed" src="images/genericperson.png"/>

                </div>
                <div class="headline" >
                    <h1> SRC ONLINE </h1>

                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 ">   

            <form action="search.php" method="post">
                <div class="input-group search">
                    <input name="search" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button name="submit" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form><!-- search form -->

       </div>

   </div>

   <div class="navigation w3-container clearfix" >


            <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav" >
                    <li> <a href='index.php'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span> Home</a></li><li> <a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-flash'></span> Latest update</a></li><li> <a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span> SSC</a></li><li class='dropdown'><a href='#' class='dropbtn' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open'></span> Study Material</a>
                                                <ul class='dropdown-content'>
                                                   <li> <a href='#' class='noBorder'>Link 1</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href='#' class='noBorder'>Link 2</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href='#' class='noBorder'>Link 3</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li><li class='dropdown'><a href='#' class='dropbtn' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-education'></span> Result</a>
                                                <ul class='dropdown-content'>
                                                   <li> <a href='#' class='noBorder'>Link 1</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href='#' class='noBorder'>Link 2</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href='#' class='noBorder'>Link 3</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li><li> <a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-file'></span> Other Exams</a></li><li> <a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-usd'></span> Other Jobs</a></li><li> <a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt'></span> Contact</a></li><li id='categoryRight'><a id= 'lastli' href='#'><img id='loginimage'  src='images/genericperson.png'> login</a></li><li class='icon'>
                                   <a id='lastli' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='myFunction()'>&#9776;</a>
                              </li>         
<!--                <li id="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li ><a href="#news"><img id="loginimage"  src="images/genericperson.png" > Log in</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li id="aboutli"><a id="aboutborder" href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li class="icon">
                    <a id="lastli" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
                </li>
-->
            </ul>

   </div>   


    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container mainContent">

        <div class="row">

            <!-- Blog Entries Column -->

            <div class="col-md-3">


            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">

               <h2 class="page-header">
                        Latest updates
                    <small>local news</small>
                    </h2>


               <div class="content_Box">    
                    <!-- First Blog Post -->
                    <h2>
                        <a href="#">First SSC post</a>
                    </h2>

                    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>2016-09-01</p>



                    <p>hola everyone. The site is getting somewhere!</p>
                </div>
                    <div class="contentBase clearfix">
                         <a class="btn author" href="index.php">Hasman404</a> 
                        <a class="btn btn-styling" href="#">Read More <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                    </div>

                    <br><br>   



               <div class="content_Box">    
                    <!-- First Blog Post -->
                    <h2>
                        <a href="#">Second post on SSC</a>
                    </h2>

                    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>2016-08-02</p>



                    <p>Now were trying to spice things up abit by adding this here.Lets see if this looks good. Need to style it all. Page heading should be resticted to one.</p>
                </div>
                    <div class="contentBase clearfix">
                         <a class="btn author" href="index.php">Peter</a> 
                        <a class="btn btn-styling" href="#">Read More <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                    </div>

                    <br><br>   


  <!--This function is responsible for your posts generation -->











            </div>

            <!-- Blog Sidebar Widgets Column -->


            <div class="col-md-3">

               <!-- Side Widget Well -->
               <div class="widget_Style">
                  <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-height="220" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">Facebook</a></blockquote></div> 
               </div>









                <!-- Blog Categories Well -->
  <!--              <div class="well">  -->




<!--
                    <h4>Blog Categories</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">


                            </ul>
                        </div>


                    </div>
-->
                    <!-- /.row -->
           <!--     </div>  -->







            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <hr>

        <!-- Footer -->

        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2016</p>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </footer>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->


    <script>

   /* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */

        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
            if (x.className === "topnav") {
                x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
                x.className = "topnav";
            }
            var y = document.getElementById("logo");
                y.className += " responsive";
            }

      </script>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>



 <!--  
   <div class="container margintop clear">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="upcomingevents">
                    <h1> Upcoming events </h1>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="highlightbox">

                </div>
                <div class="highlightbox">

                </div>
                <div class="highlightbox">

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">

                <div class="noticeboard">

                </div>

            </div>

        </div> <!-- Row ends here 

   </div>  
-->
```

Thank you in advance! I am forever grateful.

Comment: To vertically align the h1, flexbox is ideal, but only supported in modern browsers (IE 11+). Otherwise `display:table-cell` should work. If you get what you have running in a jsfiddle or codepen, I might be willing to implement it for you

Comment: @CharlieMartin Im not sure how i'd prepare a jsfiddle when my code is mostly php based. Nonetheless i tried and got something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/toxz6ufL/

Comment: if you have 3 children in header, you may either use display:table/table-cell or flex. example with flex and margins http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gwOVoA if element to display evenly are sibblings, it is much easier :)

Comment: @HassanNasir The only part of concern is the navbar, which doesn't need any php. A simple example implementation of that alone in a codepne is much more likely to get an answer. You can easily replace the images with ones available at any url on the web, so they actually work

Comment: @CharlieMartin Here is the codepen link http://codepen.io/hn13567/pen/BLaXVp